# Vectorizing for-loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I've created a for-loop.
The code runs fine, but it takes a long time to finish (11 minutes) due to the size of the dataframe.

```
for col in df.columns:
  for date in df.index:
     mask = (dat['start'] < date) & (dat['end'] > date) & (dat['plant_type'] == col)
     df.loc[date,col] = dat.loc[mask]['Difference'].sum()
```

I'd like to make the code run faster, and one way I found was with vectorizing. Since I've never tried it before, I kept getting errors and the code wouldn't run.

Here are the input dataframes

df

```
{'Fossil Gas': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Fossil Brown coal/Lignite': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Biomass': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Nuclear': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Fossil Oil': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Wind Onshore': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Solar': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Fossil Hard coal': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}, 'Other renewable': {Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 01:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 02:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 03:00:00', freq='H'): 0, Timestamp('2022-01-01 04:00:00', freq='H'): 0}}
```

dat

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 243}, 'avail_qty': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 0.0}, 'biddingzone_domain': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'HU', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'HU'}, 'businesstype': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'Unplanned outage', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'Planned maintenance'}, 'curvetype': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'A03', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'A03'}, 'docstatus': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): nan, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): nan}, 'end': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): Timestamp('2018-01-25 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00')}, 'mrid': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'doEAXAnlBP-GXBLvSXLrww', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'm7N8fbZN3jM4LLrCTgu1zw'}, 'nominal_power': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 25.0, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 95.0}, 'plant_type': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'Fossil Gas', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'Fossil Gas'}, 'production_resource_id': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): '15WDUME------PPI', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): '15WDKCE------PPQ'}, 'production_resource_location': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'Százhalombatta', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'Debrecen'}, 'production_resource_name': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'Dunamenti Erőmű', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'Debreceni Kombináltciklusú Erőmű'}, 'pstn': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 1}, 'qty_uom': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'MAW', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'MAW'}, 'resolution': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 'PT60M', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 'PT15M'}, 'revision': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 1, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 944}, 'start': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')}, 'created_doc_time': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): '2018-01-25 06:00:54+01:00', Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): '2018-12-30 15:36:00+01:00'}, 'Deleted': {Timestamp('2016-07-19 12:00:00'): 25.0, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 95.0}}
```

Could someone help me out, it would be very much appreciated?

Comment: Please provide some input data (as plain text). `print(df.head().to_dict())` and `print(dat.head().to_dict())` can help.

Comment: What is the `Difference` column in `dat` dataframe? Do you use the data from entso-e?

Comment: Maybe `Difference` column is `nominal_power`?

Comment: I just updated it. I changed the name of the column on the for loop, but didn't change it on the text.

Comment: You replaced `Odstavka` by `Deleted` but it doesn't explain what `Difference` column is? I can't reproduce your code because `Difference` column doesn't exist.

Comment: 'Difference' and 'Odstavka' were meant to be 'Deleted'.